# make div background image responsive with bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How make div with background image responsive with bootstrap 3  ??

Is it possible with img-responsive class in bootstrap 3 ??

My div is empty like below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep1 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep2 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep3 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep4 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep5 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="workflowstep workflowstep6 img-responsive">&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think its not the case to use `img-responsive` here, since it was for `<img />`

and for making the `div` background image responsive, we can use `background-size: cover;`

> background-size: cover;
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any),
> to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can
> completely cover the background positioning area

Answer (score 8):

To make background-image responsive, you can use `background-size: cover` CSS property. or if you want to stretch the background-image with resize in the div, use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

For more info on `background-size` CSS property go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: background-size does not work in IE8 and older, however you can use CSS3PIE to add a polyfill (but using CSS3PIE causes a slight performance hit).