# How to make div background image responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make div's background-image responsive.I have used bootstrap 3.3
I have written own css for background-image. My Code as follows.

```
.search-row-wrapper
{
  background:url(../../Images/frontend/MassageBanner.jpg );
  background-size: cover;
  height:400px;
  padding:50px 0;
  transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;
  -webkit-transition:all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1) 0s;width:100%;
}
```

I have gone through following same question links from stackoverflow , but they didn't work for me.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006587/how-to-make-div-background-image-responsive)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752749/make-div-background-image-responsive-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Your code is fine, do you mean to adapt the image to the size of the div at all sizes?

Comment: Yes i want to adapt div's background-image to all size like (mobile,tablet or desktop)

Comment: Try adding `background-position: center;` in there too.

Comment: Yup , (background-position: center;) it works . Thanks @ Claudiordgz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just missing `background-position: center;`, the rest is perfect

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Works in:**

> - Safari 3+
> - Chrome Whatever+
> - IE 9+
> - Opera 10+

**Method 2:**

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

**Works in:**

> - Safari / Chrome / Opera / Firefox / IE 9
> - IE 6: Borked - but probably fixable if you use some kind of fixed positioning shim
> - IE 7/8: Mostly works, doesn't center at small sizes but fills screen fine

For more information on methods and **[This article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)** useful for your ask.